# Java Spring receiving list of longs prints MismatchedInputException

Tags: java, angular, spring, http, jpa

I use the following PostMapping to receive 3 parameters:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/createJobs",
         consumes="application/json",
         produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> createJobs(
        @RequestBody ArrayList<Long> sizes,
        @RequestBody Long accounts,
        @RequestBody Long productId
) {
    
    System.out.println(sizes + " " + accounts + " " + productId);
    try {
        jobService.createJobs(productId, sizes, accounts);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
    }
    catch (final Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
}
```

I use Angular to send the post request. The data I send looks like this:

```
{
   "productId":715,
   "sizes":[3,5],
   "accounts":3
}
```

But after sending the post-request, I receive the following error:

```
.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Long>` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Long>` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is convenient to put every Request Key on method arguments with `@RequestBody`, it is **advisable** to make a generalized class for each Request Model.

e.g. My Controller:

```
ResponseEntity<TransactionLog> checkDiscount(HttpServletRequest request, 
                                             @RequestBody RequestCheckDiscount requestBody) {
    // Your code here
}
```

My Request Model:

```
public class RequestCheckDiscount {
    private String username;
    private int amount;
    private long time;

    // Standard getters and setters.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key in the body of the POST request should be **productId** and not **product**.